# Firebase: How to validate the email address when a user updates his/her email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm getting an error in Firebase. When a user updates his/her email in firebase, the user's email gets updated but the user's email doesn't get validated and so the user cannot login since the email is not valid. Is there anything else that needs to be done when a user updates their email in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to send verificationEmail to the new email using sendEmailVerification on the currentUser property of auth varible in firebase. An anomally is that sometimes the mail is sent more than once at the same time, and the link gets expired.

```
`  this.user.updateEmail(email).then(function () {
     auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(() => {
        this.notificationSystem.addNotification({
          `message`: 'Verify your new email address with the link sent to ' + email,
          level: 'info'
        })
      });`
```